# Why Does Xcode 4.3 Put @interface ClassName() in Implementation File?

Tags: xcode, cocoa, xcode4

I created a class in Xcode 4.3, and it created the header and implementation files with @interface and @implementation in the correct locations, but there is also an @interface in the implementation file like this:

```
@interface MyClassName ()

@end
```

Why does Xcode put that in the implementation file and what is it for?

Thanks,
Kurz

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Xcode automatically creates a class extension, which allows you to implement "private" methods.
Class extensions are unnamed categories and have been introduced with Objective-C 2.0.

One advantage of class extensions is, that the compiler will warn you, if you forget to implement one of the methods declared in the anonymous interface.

Comment: Another answer is: because we begged Apple to add it.... :D Many of us shouted "finally!"

Comment: Read what @bbum has to say about [class extensions](http://www.friday.com/bbum/2009/09/11/class-extensions-explained/).